# Create eyebrow-shaped element in html/css

Tags: html, css

How can you create an eyebrow-shaped element in html/css? Using

```
border-top-left-radius:100%;
border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
```

I managed to create [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lte0yf15/). However, I'd like them to look a bit more like the image below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The image is not clear , can you add a clear image ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SVG Polygon](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_polygon.asp)

I couldn't see the image clearly but I made something similar( I think it's Similar :-) )

[image]